# Derived TextBox that activates the Touch Screen Keyboard

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a project that needs to target .NET Framework 4, and I'm trying to get the touch keyboard to open when a TextBox is getting focus.
I've searched for solutions and found out that on Framework 4.6.2 and up, this is done automatically, but unfortunately I cannot target 4.6.2.

I found a solution (from [this tutorial](https://riptutorial.com/wpf/example/23104/showing-touch-keyboard-on-windows-8-and-windows-10)) that uses a class that inherits from TextBox.
The thing is, I'm not yet used to WPF, and I just created the derived class and tried to use it directly on my XAML. And, of course, it didn't work. It gave me an error saying that it couldn't find the XAML file of that class.

So then I tried creating a Custom Control, and adding the C# code into its code-behind. In the XAML file, I only added a TextBox control, so I could link the EventHandlers to it (the GetFocus and LostFocus events).
I used the x:Name property to find the TextBox, but it gave me a NullException, since the TextBox couldn't be found.

I'm really lost here now, since I don't know what approach I should take and how to make this work.

This is the Custom Control I created:

XAML

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="SistemaFichajeWPF.TouchEnabledTextBoxWPF"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SistemaFichajeWPF"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             Height="35" Width="170">
    <TextBox x:Name="tbPrincipal" FontSize="24"/>
</UserControl>
```

CS

```cs
public partial class TouchEnabledTextBoxWPF : UserControl
    {
        private Process _touchKeyboardProcess = null;
        private TextBox textBox;

        public TouchEnabledTextBoxWPF()
        {
            textBox = this.GetChildOfType<TextBox>();

            textBox.GotTouchCapture += TouchEnabledTextBox_GotTouchCapture;

            textBox.LostFocus += TouchEnabledTextBox_LostFocus;
        }

        private void TouchEnabledTextBox_LostFocus(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (_touchKeyboardProcess != null)
            {
                _touchKeyboardProcess.Kill();
                _touchKeyboardProcess = null;
            }
        }

        private void TouchEnabledTextBox_GotTouchCapture(object sender, System.Windows.Input.TouchEventArgs e)
        {
            string touchKeyBoardPath =
                @"C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Ink\TabTip.exe";
            _touchKeyboardProcess = Process.Start(touchKeyBoardPath);
        }
    }
```

Thank you a lot in advance!

Comment: You have removed the `InitializeComponent()` method call from the UserControl constructor. It won't work without it.

Comment: @Clemens Thank you very much, I totally didn't notice (my fault for just copy-pasting...), sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was, as @Clemens said in the comments, that I removed InitializeComponent(). And also the private TextBox variable is unnecessary since the TextBox already has a name.

So the CS would be:

```cs
public partial class TouchEnabledTextBoxWPF : UserControl
    {
        private Process _touchKeyboardProcess = null;

        public TouchEnabledTextBoxWPF()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            tbPrincipal.GotTouchCapture += TouchEnabledTextBox_GotTouchCapture;
            tbPrincipal.LostFocus += TouchEnabledTextBox_LostFocus;
        }

        private void TouchEnabledTextBox_LostFocus(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (_touchKeyboardProcess != null)
            {
                _touchKeyboardProcess.Kill();
                _touchKeyboardProcess = null;
            }
        }

        private void TouchEnabledTextBox_GotTouchCapture(object sender, System.Windows.Input.TouchEventArgs e)
        {
            string touchKeyBoardPath =
                @"C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Ink\TabTip.exe";
            _touchKeyboardProcess = Process.Start(touchKeyBoardPath);
        }
    }
```

Thank you a lot @Clemens!